# XPath Get value inside query string

Tags: xpath

I use this XPath

```
//@getparam
```

to get this list of URL

```
/blabla/bla.php?id=100001&target=lala&new=lulu
/blabla/bla.php?id=100002&target=lala&new=lulu
/blabla/bla.php?id=100003&target=lala&new=lulu
```

I want to get list of IDs, and try this XPath

```
substring-before(substring-after(//@getparam, "?id="), "&")
```

but it only returns first ID. How to get all IDs only using XPath?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XPath 2.0, the following will do the trick:

```
//@getparam/substring-before(substring-after(., "?id="), "&")
```

If you're using XPath 1.0, there is no single expression to return the desired result set. You can iterate over each result of `//@getParam` and apply the functions.